# Custom tooltip in WPF chart

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, wpf-controls, data-visualization

I have the following [WPF contro](https://pastebin.com/tek7S1Wi)l containing a Data Visualization Chart (while this is the [C# code](https://pastebin.com/SwArVarU) behind it). My problem is that whatever I try, I can't change the tooltips of the points.

I tried looking for other quests and I saw different kind of solutions. One kind assigned an certain event to the chart, but my LineChart doesn't have these events. I tried adding a template, but nothing happen (I still see the same tooltip)

```
<DVC:Chart Canvas.Top="80" Canvas.Left="10" x:Name="LineChart" Title="Linea" Foreground="Black" Background="{DynamicResource Brush09}" BorderBrush="Transparent" PlotAreaStyle="{DynamicResource GridStyle1}" Margin="0,5,0,0">
    <DVC:Chart.TitleStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DV:Title}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </DVC:Chart.TitleStyle>
    <DVC:Chart.LegendStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DV:Legend}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15,0"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding LegendVisibility, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource Brush09}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Brush08}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Brush09}" />
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </Style>
    </DVC:Chart.LegendStyle>
    <DVC:Chart.Axes>
        <DVC:DateTimeAxis x:Name="xAxis" Orientation="X" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="10"/>
        <DVC:LinearAxis x:Name="yAxis" Orientation="Y" Minimum="0" Foreground="Black"  FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="10">
        </DVC:LinearAxis>
    </DVC:Chart.Axes>

    <DVC:LineSeries x:Name="SeriesColumn" DependentValuePath="Value"  IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding}" Margin="0">
        <DVC:LineSeries.Background>
            <RadialGradientBrush Center="0.075,0.015" GradientOrigin="-0.1,-0.1" RadiusY="0.9" RadiusX="1.05">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFB9D6F7"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF284B70" Offset="1"/>
            </RadialGradientBrush>
        </DVC:LineSeries.Background>
    </DVC:LineSeries>
</DVC:Chart>
```

What I want is the [following result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDhX9.png). I want to keep all my values as double, but I want the tooltip to show "number+s" if the value is less then 60, while I want to see "number+m number+s" if the number is greater then 60. Is it possible?

Comment: Oh, I forgot the [c# code](https://pastebin.com/SwArVarU).

Comment: Paste the C# code in this post. Ideally, a Stackoverflow post is a self-contained entity that doesn't rely on another site like pastebin.